# Did Darth Maul love (or like) Sidious?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith

By the Rule of Two, the Sith apprentice should strive to become better than and kill his Master. However, I don't feel like Maul and Sidious's relationship was like this in their time together.

Is there evidence to suggest Maul cared for, loved, looked up to or admired Sidious?

Comment: Disney canon, or EU/Legends?

Comment: Maul was, at least according to the old EU, more of a throwaway apprentice. I forget where it was but sidious mentions Maul being more of an animal - he was a means to an end, not a successor to the mantle of the Sith

Comment: @DVK Everything is accepted, although higher level of canon should be at the top of answer and decreasing canon downwards*

Comment: Like have a canon section, then legends after

Comment: @SSummer  Totally agree.  But that is from Sidious's perspective.  This question is specifically for Maul's perspective i.e. I'm not really interested in what Sidious thought of Maul (a tool).

Comment: Neither the Junior nor Official novelisations give us much info. Basically Maul is really keen to kill the Jedi. It repeats that over and over again. He likes Sidious just fine when he's being told to kill Jedi and he's described as "impatient" when Sidious suggests a plan involving anything other than killing the Jedi.

Comment: @Richard I can say I agree from having read Saboteur, Shadow Hunter and seeing The Clone Wars.  However I know Maul exists in more than what I've seen/read so I thought evidence of my question can be answered from sources elsewhere.

Comment: @Richard It's unclear to me, judging from your comment, what Maul's attitude is towards the Jedi, re: killing them.

Comment: I heard they had an insidious relationship.

Comment: @AndresF. - He's a complex character,  for sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Disney Canon:

Nothing, really, that I could find.

### EU/Legends:

**UPDATE:** He's clearly willing to live by the Rule of Two. And he has disdain for "love".

From "Star Wars Episode I Journal: Darth Maul"

> Always remember, my apprentice: Anger is a living thing. Feed it and it will grow.
>
> I learned to see through the eyes of my Master. He showed me the galaxy and explained it in terms of power - who had it, who did not. He showed me that vast resources are there for the taking. The concerns of most beings are petty. Food and shelter are nothing. **Love or devotion to a fellow being, a world, or a cause is not only a distraction but a danger, for it can be used against you. I have seen my Master use that weakness in others for his own ends. Did you know that there are those willing to die for someone they love?**. **So puzzling.**
>
> I am willing to die for my Master, of course. **But he is not just a being**. He is a tradition, a heritage, an ideal. **Someday I will be Master and have my own apprentice**. He will be willing to die for me.

The last paragraph is telling:

- He's willing to die for Sidious NOT because of his feelings about Sidious as a person, but as his Sith Master
- He expects to be a Sith Master eventually, which means he accepts the eventuality that he would have to kill Sidious (even though this journal mostly talks about eventuality of Sidious dying on a mission)

**Original answer**

He's in awe of Sidious, and "lives to serve him":

> **"My Master, " Maul said. "I live to serve you."**
>
> Sidious fell briefly silent never a good sign. "There are certainties, Darth Maul," he said at last. "But there is also the unforeseen. The power of the dark side is limitless, but only to those who accept uncertainty. That means being able to concede to possibilities."
>
> Darth Sidious raised his right hand, palm outward.
>
> Before Maul could prevent it, even if he had chosen to do so, the long cylinder that was his double-bladed lightsaber flew from its hitch on his belt and went directly to his Master. But instead of grasping it, Sidious stopped the lightsaber in midflight, centimeters from his raised hand, and directed it to spin and rotate before him, **leaving Maul to gaze at him in unabashed awe**.
>
> (*Darth Maul: Saboteur*)

He was willing to die on Sidious' orders (which of course conflicts with killing him):

> It was impossible even to conceive of a time when he had not been in thrall to Darth Sidious. He knew that he had come originally from a world called Iri-donia, but knowing that was like knowing that the atoms composing his body had originally been born in the primordial galactic furnaces that had forged the stars. The knowledge was interesting in a remote, academic way, but no more than that. He had no interest whatsoever in learning any more about his past or his homeworld. **As far as he was concerned, his life began with Lord Sidious**. **And if his master ordered an end to that life, Maul would accept that judgment with no argument**.
>   (*Darth Maul: Shadow Hunter*)

Comment: I think your second point is fantastic, but I'm not sure how reliable that first statement is. Saying he lives to serve sounds like a plausible platitude, not necessarily an indication of a deeper feeling

Comment: @SSumner - agreed. Narrator's "awe" statement is more illuminating